# How to assign value if a value of one dataframe is in range of another dataframe?

Tags: python, range

I have two dataframes of which a subset is presented below:

df1:

```
    Omschrijving bouwdeelsoort  Wegnummer   Hectometer bord
6   Camera (beweegbaar)         0.0         41.5    
7   Kast                        1.0         29.5    
8   Kast                        1.0         40.4
20  Kast                        1.0         30.4
```

df2:

```
    Code systeemdeel    van km  tot km  Wegnummer
    1   000_0010_R      40.4    50.7    0.0
    2   001_0040_R      28.885  39.5    1.0
    4   001_0050_R      39.5    46.4    1.0
```

I try to assign the values of df2 column "Code systeemdeel" to the corresponding values of df1 based on a match and if a value is of df1 is in the range of "van km" and "tot km". Thus, I try to obtain the following dataframe:

```
    Omschrijving bouwdeelsoort  Wegnummer   Hectometer bord  Code systeemdeel
6   Camera (beweegbaar)         0.0         41.5             000_0010_R    
7   Kast                        1.0         29.5             001_0040_R                 
8   Kast                        1.0         40.4             001_0050_R
20  Kast                        1.0         30.4             001_0040_R
```

I tried the following code, but then the rows are filtered if no match is found which is not desirable

```
data_importeren["Specifieke omschrijving object"] = ""    
DF_out = data_importeren.merge(systeemdelen, how='cross').query('(Wegnummer_x == Wegnummer_y) & (Hectometer bord >= van km) & (Hectometer bord <= tot km)')
```

I tried another piece of code which provides me with the desired result, however I think this code can be more improved:

```
wegnummer_range_mapping = {}
for index, row in systeemdelen.iterrows():
    wegnr = row["Wegnummer"]
    if wegnr not in wegnummer_range_mapping:
        wegnummer_range_mapping[wegnr] = []
    wegnummer_range_mapping[wegnr].append((row["van km"], row["tot km"], row["Code systeemdeel"]))

# Function to assign the appropriate 'Code systeemdeel' based on the range
def assign_code(row):
    wegnr = row["Wegnummer"]
    if wegnr in wegnummer_range_mapping:
        for start, end, code in wegnummer_range_mapping[wegnr]:
            if start <= row["Locatie"] <= end:
                return code
    return None

# Apply the function to create the "Code systeemdeel" column in df1
df1["Code systeemdeel"] = df1.apply(assign_code, axis=1)
```

Comment: Read the documentation of the `query` method, especially the part about spaces in column names.

Comment: Correct I changed the white space with "_" and the error is solved. However, the query filters the rows with the required condition. But I also want to keep the rows which don't have a match with df2. How can I do that?